# How can I combine my columns into one to create a URI in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have four columns that I would like to combine into one URL:  region_slug, category_slug, listing_slug, and listing_id.  Previously, I have been using PHP to do this but this can be repetitive, especially if I ever decide to change the format of the URI.  I would like a single alias to return a URI like '{region_slug}/{category_slug}/{listing_slug}/{listing_id}.  So I would basically like to do something like `<?php echo $result['listing_uri']; ?>`  How could I do this with my current query:

```
        SELECT
            l.listing_id, l.slug AS listing_slug, r.region_id, r.slug AS region_slug, c.category_id, c.slug AS category_slug
        FROM listings AS l 
        LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON l.category_id = c.category_id
        LEFT JOIN regions AS r ON l.region_id = r.region_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONCAT_WS`, this function allows your to concatenate strings with a separator:

```
SELECT
    l.listing_id AS listing_id,
    l.slug AS listing_slug, 
    r.region_id, r.slug AS region_slug, 
    c.category_id, c.slug AS category_slug,
    CONCAT_WS('/', region_slug, category_slug, listing_slug, listing_id) AS listing_uri
FROM 
    listings AS l 
LEFT JOIN 
    categories AS c ON l.category_id = c.category_id
LEFT JOIN 
    regions AS r ON l.region_id = r.region_id
```